# How to list all items in a table by filtering another in mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, join

I have 2 tables

**Table 1 = visitacli**

```
codcli-char(3)
nomecli-varchar(100)
------------------------
001 - Joao
002 - Maria
003 - Joana
```

**Table 2 = visitaate**

```
codcli-char(3)
datavisita-char(8)
quantidade-integer
-------------------------
001 - 20170810 - 2
001 - 20170811 - 3
001 - 20170815 - 5
002 - 20170812 - 1
002 - 20170816 - 9
```

My select

```
    SELECT
    visitacli.codcli,
    visitacli.nomecli,
    Sum(visitaate.quantidade) AS totalvisitas
FROM
    visitacli
LEFT JOIN visitaate ON visitacli.codcli = visitaate.codcli
WHERE
    visitaate.datavisita >= '20170801'
AND visitaate.datavisita <= '20170817'
GROUP BY
    visitacli.codcli,
    visitacli.nomecli
```

Result:

```
001 - Joao - 10
002 - Maria - 10
```

But... not list `003 - Joana`.
How to list all items in table one with the total of table 2?

Answer (score 1):

You have to move the predicates of the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE
    visitaate.datavisita >= '20170801'
AND visitaate.datavisita <= '20170817'
```

to

```
LEFT JOIN visitaate 
   ON visitacli.codcli = visitaate.codcli
      AND visitaate.datavisita >= '20170801'
      AND visitaate.datavisita <= '20170817'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an outer join. Just summing makes an inner join only showing data present in BOTH tables. Right or Left outer join should do what you need.